# zsh - Why is PSVAR not an array variable?

Tags: zsh

Why does `PSVAR` behave as a string, while other array variables behave as expected?

```
% ARR[1]='a'
% ARR[2]='b'
% ARR[3]='c'
% echo $arr
a b c

% PSVAR[1]='a'
% PSVAR[2]='b'
% PSVAR[3]='c'
% echo $PSVAR
abc
```

This experiment tells that `PSVAR` is not an array variable.

```
% PSVAR=()
zsh: PSVAR: attempt to assign array value to non-array
```

[The documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html) makes it clear than `PSVAR` **is** an array. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PSVAR` and `psvar` are related as if the command

```
typeset -T PSVAR psvar
```

had been issued

Since `PSVAR` isn't actually an array,

```
% typeset -p PSVAR psvar
typeset PSVAR=''
typeset -a psvar=(  )
```

assigning to it as if it were seems to modify an individual *character*, rather than an element of the array. Each element of PSVAR corresponds to a single character in the array `psvar`, including the `:` that separates array elements.

```
% psvar=(1234 5678)
% print -l $psvar
1234
5678
% print -l $PSVAR
1234:5678
% PSVAR[1]=foo
% PSVAR[8]=bar
% print -l $psvar
foo234
bar678
```

The assignment to `PSVAR[1]` "stretched" the length of `PSVAR`, hence the assignment to `PSVAR[8]` rather than `PSVAR[6]` to replace `5` with `bar`.

Comment: the problem was that I didn't know about the difference between PSVAR and psvar - I considered them synonymous. Thank you for pointing my attention to `typeset -T`, that made everything clear. And yes, when subscripts are applied to scalar variables, they behave as if they were arrays of chars - that's the documented behavior. Thank you again.